# Computer randomly changes system language to French

Tags: windows-vista, language

One of my Dad's colleagues asked me to fix their Windows Vista laptop which randomly changed its language from English (which it had been installed with) to French. I did not obtain much information on or why this occurred other than that it was completely spontaneous and they couldn't fix it. They did preform a system restore on the device, but from what I heard it did not fix the problem. I also observed that the owners had completely cleared all of their data off of the device and factory defaulted the computer when I received it for fixing.

I Did fix the computer, simply by preforming a System Reset (Completely formatting its HDD and reinstalling the operating system). During the operating system install, I was prompted with an option to set the system's language to either English or French. I Would also like to note that at the bottom of the language selection window there was a message saying that the language **Could Not** be changed after the OS was installed, confusing me even more why or how the problem could occur in the first place.

Before I did the above, though, I tried fixing it internally from the operating system. Not possessing the knowledge of how to read or speak French, I could not tell what settings I was attempting to change or where they would be located. The operating system seemed to be stable, and as it had been cleared out, it seemed very implausible that this could have been caused by a virus or some malware.

So my question is, even though I solved the problem, why did it even occur in the first place? I would like to know so that I can add to my knowledge on why such problems happen.

*and for those of you who were wondering, here are the computer's specs:*

- Computer: Compaq Presario CQ60-209TU (I'm pretty sure)
- AMD Turion Dual core 2.00 GHz
- 3.00 GB RAM
- NVidia GPU (I cannot remember the exact specs, but I'm pretty sure it's 512 MB)
- 250 GB 7500 RPM HDD
- Windows Vista Home Premium 64-bit

Answer (score 0):

Start->Panel->Languages->Other->System Language: French.

Try "Change system language". Add to English language.

Comment: Not useful to the question- I already fixed it via other means, and was wanting to know why it happened in the first place. Additionally, as I stated earlier, during the windows install, I was notified that once the operating system was installed, the system language could not be changed. If this is truth, which I believe it to be, your answer is invalid.